Postgres websearch_to_tsquery and OR in query in different languages
I have a task of full-text search in fields that may contain Russian, English and mixed phrases. User input assumes that the query contains words in both languages. At the same time, I would like the words from the query to be searched by OR.
To solve this problem, I constructed the following index
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_tsvector (name text)
    RETURNS tsvector AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN (setweight(to_tsvector('russian', name), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('english', name), 'B'));
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX projects_fts_name_idx ON projects USING gin (make_tsvector(name)); 

and I use the following query:
find = find.replace(' ', ' OR ');
result = await pool.query(`
                SELECT *,
                    ts_rank(make_tsvector(name), q_ru) AS r_ru,
                    ts_rank(make_tsvector(name), q_en) AS r_en
                FROM projects_v,
                    websearch_to_tsquery('russian', $1) AS q_ru,
                    websearch_to_tsquery('english', $1) AS q_en
                WHERE make_tsvector(name) @@ q_ru AND make_tsvector(name) @@ q_en
                ORDER BY r_ru DESC, r_en DESC
                LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3`,
                [ find, limit, offset ]);

In this case, I encountered the following problem:
Here is the phrase "good day день который"
websearch_to_tsquery('russian', $1) converts to "'good' | 'day' & 'ден' & 'котор'"
websearch_to_tsquery('english', $1) converts to "'good' | 'day' & 'день' & 'который'"

i.e. for some reason, if the words are in both languages, then the Russian "words" are listed through &
Now let's take only the Russian words "день который" and get:
websearch_to_tsquery('russian', $1) converts to "'ден' | 'котор'"
websearch_to_tsquery('english', $1) converts to "'день' | 'который'"

i.e. if the words are only Russian, they are separated by | (as I wanted).
How can I make it so that the words are always separated by | ? Or, perhaps, is there some other way to solve my problem?

I don't think that is a database problem. Look at the contents of find after the replace().

Oh my God! You're absolutely right! It completely slipped my mind that replace() would only make one substitution in this case. Shame on me!
